# NLP - How to Identify whether 2 texts refer to similar object

Tags: nlp, semantics, similarity, sentence-similarity

I am looking for some general guidance here.

> The high-level use case is such that I receive some product documents
>   from which I need to extract some information and process it. Before
>   doing that, I need to verify that the document is actually referring
>   to the correct product. For that I need to validate the product
>   heading/description from document against what I know to be correct.

So I have 2 texts

1. Text 1 - this refers to the product information extracted from some document
2. Text 2 - this is the actual product heading/description available with me, which can be considered as correct.

I need to validate that both texts refer to same product or object.

Example:

```
Text 1 (to be validated) - Optimus Prime Costume, Blue, with good packaging and warranty
Text 2 (correct info) - Optimus Prime Blue Costume, Medium Size`
```

You see, I need to validate that both text refer to `Optimus Prime Costume`.

I tried following methods -

- Cosine Similarity
- TF-IDF similarity
- Overlapping words between strings

But the problem with them is that they depends on the entire text rather than the primary object being referred in the text.

I was thinking of processing as follows:-

- Remove colors, size info etc. from the text 2. The text 2, is very concise and does not contain random data. It contains product name and size, colour info.
- Validate that the remaining elements from Text 2 are present in Text 1, or atleast a majority of them are.

I am not quite sure what different NLP techniques might be there, which would be better than this approach, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your target this can be medium-hard or very hard.

There are a couple of things you can use:

NER would definitely be helpful: 
[image]

Wikifier could be useful too: http://cogcomp.org/page/demo_view/Wikifier

And also Semantic-Role-Labeling. See more annotations here: http://nlp.cogcomp.org/

It's hard to judge from one single example what is the exact algorithm, but if you have more examples might be easier to come up with a better formalization.

An extension of this can be found in what has been used 
[in this work.](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~danielkh/files/2018_semanticilp/2018_aaai_semanticilp.pdf)

Comment: Your last link isn't working. Can you double check that?

Comment: Should be fixed now.